# Get content from xml in java

Tags: java, xml

I have the following xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<company>
    <staff>
        <firstname>yong</firstname>
        <lastname>mook kim</lastname>
        <nickname>mkyong</nickname>
        <salary>100000</salary>
    </staff>
    <staff>
        <firstname>low</firstname>
        <lastname>yin fong</lastname>
        <nickname>fong fong</nickname>
        <salary>200000</salary>
    </staff>
</company>
```

I'm using the sax parser to get the information from this file. Is there a way to get the complete content from an element?

Let say I identified the element "staff", how can I get:

```
<firstname>low</firstname>
<lastname>yin fong</lastname>
<nickname>fong fong</nickname>
<salary>200000</salary>
```

?

Comment: Use a xml parsing library like Jsoup.  You can use css-like selectors to get elements, then traverse the ancestor nodes.

Comment: Do you want a string containing `"<firstname>low</firstname>...<salary>20000</salary>"` or a collection of `org.w3c.dom.Element`s?

Comment: I am not sure about SAX lib. But anyway I suggest you to: 1) first get the object of the parent <staff> node; 2)and try to examine whether there is a "inline" or "text" or whatever member could give the raw data within that node

Answer (score 1):

You should use a DOM parser.  You can load the content like so:

```
final org.w3c.dom.Document doc = javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new java.io.File("myFile.xml");
```

Now you can get the staff elements like so:

```
final org.w3c.dom.NodeList staff = doc.getElementsByTagName("staff");
```

Finally, you can write the content of the first staff element to stdout like so:

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory.transform(
    new javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource(staff.item(1)), //Assuming you want to print only the second <staff> element.
    new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(System.out));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use DOM if you want not just the content but tag information as well. DOM lets you get NODE information like child nodes etc.

Answer (score 0):

A dom parser would be suitable here, but if you wanted to you could use `XPath` - or searching library for XML. Here is the way to do it for you example:

```
try{
    DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    documentBuilderFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
    DocumentBuilder builder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("YourPath-ToXML-File");

    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();

    XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile("/company/staff[2]/*");

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) expression.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    for(int i = 0;i<nodes.getLength();i++){
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeName());
        System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getTextContent());
    }
} catch(Exception exception){
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should look into JAXB, its really easy to use. All you need are some annotated beans. In your case a bean for Company and one for Staff. It can handle both marshaling and unmarshaling.